# How to merge data frame entries of one column based on duplicate entries of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

So I have a pandas dataframe containing columns 'body' and 'tag_text'. Body is some text, and tag_text is a tag given to that text. The dataframe is organized as follows

- Each body only has one tag,
- A Body that would have multiple tags is represented by duplicate entries of that body in the dataframe, with each entry having a different tag_text value.

Example:
*body, tag_text*
"hi", "greeting"
"hi", "english"
"adios", "farewell"
"adios", "spanish"

So, my question is how do I efficiently make a new dataframe such that:

- Each body only occurs once in the data frame
- The tag_text field for each body is now a list of tags containing all tags that corresponded to that body.

Example:
*body,   tag_text*
"hi",    ["greeting", "english"]
"adios", ["farewell", "spanish"]
Here's my quick and dirty way, but its pretty inefficient. So I'd be interested if people have better ideas.

```
def mergeTagsByBody(df):
    bodies = df['body']
    unique_bodies = list(set(bodies))   

    unique_tags = []
    for body in unique_bodies:
        body_tags = df[df['body'] == body]['tag_text']
        unique_tags.append(body_tags)

    return pd.DataFrame({'body': unique_bodies, 'tag_text': unique_tags})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["hi", "greeting"], 
     ["hi", "english"], 
     ["adios", "farewell"], 
     ["adios", "spanish"]], 
    columns=["body", "tag_text"]
)

def tags_to_list(g):
    tags = list(g["tag_text"])
    return pd.DataFrame([[g["body"].iloc[0], tags]], columns=["body", "tags"])

(df.groupby("body")
   .apply(tags_to_list)
   .reset_index(drop=True))
#     body                 tags
# 0  adios  [farewell, spanish]
# 1     hi  [greeting, english]
```

Comment: narly... Thanks!